# Three.js new clipping mask inside other clipping mask

Tags: three.js, mask, clipping

Is it possible to create a new clipping mask inside a other clipping mask in Three.js?

I can create a fiddle to show you what I have, but I think in Three.js it's not possible to have multiple clipping masks inside a mask. In my code the older clipping mask is getting ignored, after I try to create a new clipping mask inside the older clipping mask.

Thanks in advance for the awnser.

Comment: Yes, a Fiddle would be a good idea...

Comment: On http://jsfiddle.net/f7aok1y6/178/ you can see that `maskPass2` is getting ignored. I wanted to have a torus as a mask for the red cube with the green background. That torus should have been clipped by a bigger cube, but it's getting ignored in my code.

Comment: Did you check out [this](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_postprocessing_masking) example? I am not sure what you want to achieve... Can you be more specific?

Comment: Of course. I started from that example. I wanted to have a torus with a background, that has a random color, inside a big cube and a small red cube with a green background inside that torus.